# Change formatting of Date parameter on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

So I have a custom post type called "wp_events", and I would like to update this portion:

[image]

Where is says "Scheduled 2023/11/05 by default, I would like this format:

Scheduled
November 5th, 2023 at 7:00PM

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I updated my "General" time and date format, but it isn't translating to this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `post_date_column_time` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_date_column_time/) to change the time format. The documentation says it changes the "published time of the post", but it will change the scheduled time as well ([ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59029)).

Tested:

```php
add_filter( 'post_date_column_time', static function ( $time, $post ) {
    if ( 'wp_events' !== get_post_type( $post ) || 'future' !== get_post_status( $post ) ) {
        return $time;
    }

    return sprintf(
        __( '%1$s at %2$s' ),
        get_the_time( __( 'F jS, Y' ), $post ),
        get_the_time( __( 'g:iA' ), $post )
    );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, worked perfectly! I tried multiple different things and couldn't figure it out so this is super helpful.